# How to expose selected options in React-Select so it says "X Options selected" instead of showing selected options within the select box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

React-select is a great tool but right now I'm struggling to fix a problem that I created myself (problem of over-selling).

What react select provides: [image]

It lists all the selected options within the select box which becomes cluttered overtime.

What I'm trying to achieve is: [image]

I want to show "X options selected". Also, if react-select provides managing external filters it'll be great. Otherwise, I will manually create a external filtering system. But if someone can just help me with "2 options selected"

Answer (score 1):

You can create and pass a custom value container to react-select:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

// Sample options for the Select
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
  // ... add more options
];

// Custom ValueContainer component
const CustomValueContainer = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const length = props.getValue().length;
  
  // Check if more than one option is selected
  if (length > 1) {
    // Return a custom display
    return (
      <div className="value-container">
        {length} Options Selected
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  // Return default display for other cases
  return (
    <div className="value-container">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        isMulti
        options={options}
        components={{
          ValueContainer: CustomValueContainer
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the list of all components: https://react-select.com/components